# Unbounded sequences in a general totally ordered set without max

Tags: order-theory

Does any totally ordered set $S$ does not have a maximal element have a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements in the set such that the sequence is unbounded?

In your answer I am looking for a proof, counterexample, or reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider the totally ordered set $[0,1]$.

**Update:**

Still. No. Consider the totally ordered set $\omega_1$ of countable ordinals. Since  the sup of a countable sequence of countable ordinals, is again a countable ordinal, *every* *countable* sequence is bounded in $\omega_1$. Moreover, as $\omega_1$ is a limit ordinal, it has no largest element.

Comment: No, [0,1] has a maximum element.

Comment: @WilliamElliot the original question did not have that 'maximal element' carve out.